# Using viewmodellocator on projects without app.xaml declaration

Tags: c#, mvvm-light

I'm working on a add-in to Revit and want to use mvvm light. My problem is that the program runs my dll and I don't have a app.xaml to declare the singleton for viewmodellocator as a resource for the application, what is the best approach to declare this as a resource?

Revit runs my code as commands declared in separate classes in my solution that implements a IExternalCommand interface. Could I set this resource from code behind before calling my MainWindow? Or can I set it as a resource of my mainwindow.xaml?

**EDITED**

So far we have trided the code belov, but we get error on first time run on the command, but no error on the second time the command is used.

Sample code from the command class CheckerCommand.cs

```
[Transaction(TransactionMode.Manual)]
public class CheckerCommand : IExternalCommand
{
    #region IExternalCommand Members Implementation        

    public Result Execute(ExternalCommandData revit, ref string message, ElementSet elements)
    {
        new ViewModelLocator();
        MainWindow window = new MainWindow(revit);

        try
        {
            WindowInteropHelper helper = new WindowInteropHelper(window)
            {
                Owner = Autodesk.Windows.ComponentManager.ApplicationWindow
            };

            window.ShowDialog();

            return Result.Succeeded;
        }

        catch (Autodesk.Revit.Exceptions.OperationCanceledException)
        {
            // Element selection cancelled.
            return Result.Cancelled;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            message = e.ToString();

            try
            { 
                MessageBox.Show(message, "Fatal error");
                window.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
                return Result.Failed;
            }

            return Result.Succeeded;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Here is some sample code on MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="QMChecker.Views.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:QMChecker.Views"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:QMChecker.ViewModel"   
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:mvvm="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    Title="QMChecker" Height="700" Width="1200">
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/QMChecker;component/Resources/CombinedResources.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.DataContext>
    <Binding Path="Main" Source="{StaticResource Locator}"/>
</Window.DataContext>
</Window>
```

Sample code from code-behind MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{    
    public MainWindow(ExternalCommandData _revit)
    {
        try
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;   
        }

        ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>().Revit = _revit;
    }
}
```

Sample code from ViewModelLocator.cs

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the ViewModelLocator class.
    /// </summary>
    /// 

    public ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<SpatialContainmentViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<SpatialContainmentDemandViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<RunChecksViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<SpatialContainmentParameterSummaryViewModel>();
    }

    public MainViewModel Main { get { return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>(); } }
    public SpatialContainmentViewModel SpatialContainment { get { return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<SpatialContainmentViewModel>(); } }
    public SpatialContainmentDemandViewModel SpatialContainmentDemand { get { return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<SpatialContainmentDemandViewModel>(); } }
    public RunChecksViewModel RunChecks { get { return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<RunChecksViewModel>(); } }
    public SpatialContainmentParameterSummaryViewModel SpatialContainmentParameterSummary { get { return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<SpatialContainmentParameterSummaryViewModel>(); } }

    public static void Cleanup()
    {
        SimpleIoc.Default.Unregister<MainViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Unregister<SpatialContainmentViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Unregister<SpatialContainmentDemandViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Unregister<RunChecksViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Unregister<SpatialContainmentParameterSummaryViewModel>();
    }
}
```

And I have to use ResourceDictionary on every UserControl

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Comment: Show some code that you've tried so far.

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, I know, but after some searching I haven't found an answer elsewhere. I just got this partially working, here's what I have:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
...
public MainWindow()
{
    Resources.Add("Locator", new ViewModelLocator());

    InitializeComponent();
}
...
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window 
...

    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AppleCMS.ModelHarvesterAddin"
    DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
...
```

The rest is standard for MVVMLight. The key piece, I think, is the `Resources.Add("Locator", new ViewModelLocator());` in the code-behind.

This works when running the addin. It doesn't look like MVVMLight's design-time data works yet though. I also haven't added multiple views yet, but I suspect I'll need the above in every view.